# find_or_create_by using mongoid and sidekiq leads to duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, sidekiq

Rails 4.0.2, Mongoid git alpha, sidekiq 2.17.0

Using a worker to parse a CSV file and put the contents into mongo, but running into several issues... Most obvious is a product with the same name end up as duplicate documents while using find_or_create_by.

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String

  has_many :products
end

Class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

  belongs_to: :category
end

Class ProductWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(category, name)
    category = Category.find_or_create_by( title: category )
    product = Product.find_or_create_by(name: name)
    product.category = category
    product.save
  end
end
```

With a CSV file with only two products in the same category, I'll end up with two entries for category with the same name, each product in separate categories. When I remove sidekiq async and perform it on the model directly I get the correct result of 1 category with two relational products.

It makes sense that if the workers perform the `find_and_create_by` fast enough, both workers will find nil and thus create new objects. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Also to note, I am converting this from an postgresql version of the app. The postgresql version performed the async CSV import with duplicated fields correctly.

Comment: Would uniqueness validation be a solution here?

Comment: I started out with validating unique category names, however I removed it because it ended up with `category_id: nil` on the first product, the second product was correct

Comment: Limiting sidekiq to only 1 worker seems to solve the issue, though it's less than ideal...

Comment: I can just suggest taking a look at some locking gems like https://github.com/afeld/mongoid-locker or https://github.com/burgalon/mongoid_optimistic_locking. Let us know if you'll find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Uniqueness validation is not enough, because they are defined at model level by Mongoid.

The only way to guarantee uniqueness is defining [unique indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/index-unique/):

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String

  has_many :products

  index({ title: 1 }, background: true, unique: true)

  validates_uniqueness_of :title
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's missing a [uniqueness validation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html).

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String

  has_many :products

  validates_uniqueness_of :title  # Won't duplicate records
end
```

You can also use a different, [more accurate querying](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html):

`Category.where(title: category).first_or_create!`

This way you can even `rescue` if something else goes wrong.

Comment: Check my comment on this. That was my first thought but it would overwrite the first item setting category to nil,second item would have correct category.